# What Happens In a HashMap If we give 2^30 initial size and load factor= 1?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I have searched a lot but didn't find around the same:-
How does the hashmap resize works if it reaches to max capacity in this case?
Does it throw some exception because it can't increase its size max size(2<<30)?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the source code, it just stops resizing itself beyond that maximum size.

Meaning that (if you can even reach this point without running out of memory first), you don't get any additional buckets. But you could not get a lot more anyway, as `hashCode` returns an `int`, and with 2^30 you have already pretty much maxed out the range there, too. Arrays in Java cannot grow beyond being `int`-indexed, either (and the HashMap buckets are stored in an array).

Assuming again you have enough memory, you can continue adding more elements, they will just "collide" into the same buckets.